# Django Project with CSS embedded images

Tags: python, css, django

I have created a Django project that will be built into various environments: Dev, Test, Prod, etc.  I have quite a few CSS files, and some of them have embedded images.  For example:

```
.logo {
   background-image: url(http://{server:port}/static/logo.png);
   height: 58px;
   width: 239px;
}
```

For each environment, there may be a different server and port that will serve the static content.

What would be the most efficient method (along withe Django's best practices) to allow CSS files to take into account various environments?

Comment: what about linking different css files in html depending on env?

Comment: Having a different set of CSS files per env is an option, but I'd rather have 1 set to manage rather than multiple variations.  Thanks though.

Comment: Why not use relative path and use django configuration to manage which server it will be using?

Comment: That is a possibility, but in the near future I may need to decouple serving static content from the same server as the Django app.

Answer (score 0):

Hassan,

The Django best practice for this would be to pass the server port to the image as "context" and have the image called based on that.

So a simple **views.py**

```
def image_view(request, server_port):
  return render(request, 'image_page.html', {'server_port': server_port})
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
  url(r'image_view/(?P<server_port>\d+)/$', views.image_view, name='image_view'),
  )
```

Then in your **image_page.html**

```
<body>
  <img src="{{ STATIC_URL }}{{ server_port }}logo.png" alt="" />
</body>
```

The **url** to get to this view/html page:

```
<a href="{% url 'image_view' 'server_port' %}">Link</a>
```

Your are not able to pass context variables to `.css` files using Django. Not that I am aware of. Hope that helps.  Remember to configure `STATIC_URL` in your `settings.py` for this to work.  And your **server_port** will also need to match the directories where images are stored in order for Django to look up the image using the file path.

Comment: Thanks Aron - I agree regarding passing context variables to .css files. I have not read anywhere in the documentation that Django supports passing variables into CSS files unless you do serve them through the template engine (which has its own issues).

Comment: Yes, a server port is something that you may not want to put in your urls!

Answer (score 0):

At the end of the day, I decided to just use the "Production" server/port in all my CSS files.  Then at each tier prior to Production, just update the host file to point the Prod server/port for static content to the appropriate IP address.